# How do I make in Cortex+ an opposing dice pool when there are NPCs on both sides?

Tags: cortex-plus, firefly

I want to have a scene which is a firefight between 10 Browncoats (6 players and 4 NPCs) and 10 Alliance troopers (all NPCs).  So no-one is outnumbered or outgunned.

I’m guessing the Alliance dice pool is 10d8 Alliance Trooper + d12 Warzone firefight. (Eeek that’s buckets of dice. I don’t think I even own 10d8).

How do I represent the NPCs on the players’ side?  Do I…

- Give the players 4d8 in their dice pool to represent the NPCs as warm bodies on their side?
- Or give the players a d12 Asset of “You have 4 trusty NPCs” in their dice pool?
- Remove 4d8 from the Alliance dice pool to reduce it to 6d8 + d12?
- Ignore the large number of troopers because both sides have the same numbers of men, and roll a simple Attribute + d8 Alliance Trooper + d12 Warzone firefight?
- Something else I haven’t thought of...